# Execute a src script inserted with .innerHTML

Tags: javascript, json

I'm working on Blogger. I have a function (showmusic, which takes a json code as parameter) that show my posts and I'm calling it like this:

```
<script src='/feeds/posts/default/-/Album/Pop?max-results=20&orderby=published&alt=json-in-script&callback=showmusic'></script>
```

I'm looking for a way to change the labels ("Album" and "Pop") with `<select>` tags and for that I need to insert that script with innerHTML, but the script doesn't execute:

```
function myFunction(label1,label2) {
  var label1 += "/";
  var label2 += "/";
  var script = "\x3Cscript src='/feeds/posts/default/-/"+label1+label2+"?max-results=20&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=showmusic'>\x3C/script>"
  document.getElementById("my-container").innerHTML = script;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean "*execute same script but with .innerHTML*"?

Comment: So you want to add the `<script>` tag dynamically? Does it already work? Is the tag added but not executed?

Comment: That sounds like an absolute no-go for security reasons.

Comment: *"for that I need to insert that script with innerHTML, but the script doesn't execute"* `innerHTML` does not execute inserted scripts. So that's not the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Try it out:

```
function myFunction( label1, label2 ) {
    var s = document.createElement( "script" );
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.async = true;
    s.src = "/feeds/posts/default/-/" + label1 + label2 + "?max-results=20&amp;orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=showmusic";
    document.getElementById( "my-container" ).appendChild( s );
}
```

I'm made simple test. Create HTML page with this content:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function getJavascript() {
                var s = document.createElement( "script" );
                s.type = "text/javascript";
                s.async = true;
                s.src = "get_javascript.js";
                document.getElementById( "javascriptHolder" ).appendChild( s );
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button type="button" onclick="getJavascript();">Get Javascript</button>
        <div id="javascriptHolder"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

And file `get_javascript.js` with this:

```
alert( 'I am from Javascript' );
```

And when I click on button all works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible unless the script inserting the tag is inline within the HTML, but at that point, why don't you just insert the tag in there normally instead?

If the injection script is loaded as a reference, the injected script tag will not be executed; by the time your script runs to inject the tag the DOM has already loaded and will not execute any scripts that were not present at the time of loading.